# Flutter adding to Custom Drawer

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

After years and years of lurking I've finally got a problem which I can't solve with existing questions.
My problem is this. I'm working with a student group on an app and I'm not that familiar with Flutter. I want to expand the drawer but I don't know how.
My piece of code is as follows:

```
drawer: CustomDrawer(
    scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey,
    customListTile: ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
      title: Text('Calendar'),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CalendarScreen())
        );
      }
    ),
  )
```

I want to add more Tiles. How do I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "expand the drawer"? I see that you already created a class named ```CustomDrawer```

Comment: Where I already have a Tile "Calander", I want to add a second tile called "Home".

Comment: That might need to be done on the CustomDrawer class, since you need to create another param there to then paint it. Do you mind sharing the code of that class?

Comment: Also is worth to mention, that you do not need a custom drawer to add more than one ListTile to it.

Comment: You're right, I found another "drawer.dart". This file is rather huge. I've read through it and I guess we need to search in this piece of code:  Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context){
                    if(customListTile != null){
                      return customListTile;
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  }
                )

Answer (score 0):

```
drawer: Drawer(
child: ListView(
children: <Widget>[
  ListTile(
    title: Text("Ttem 1"),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
  ),
  ListTile(
    title: Text("Item 2"),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
  ),
 ],
),
),
```

please try this way.You will get solution of your problem.